# Can I force wrapping of all items with CSS flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have three block elements that I'm laying out with CSS Flexbox. (In my case, they happen to be two `<select>s` on either side of a `<div>ider` element; I'm building a List Builder control.)

What I want is:

- To have the middle (divider) element take up the minimum amount of space possible.
- To have the element on either end (ie: the select controls) have a minimum width, and grow to fill the possible space.
- To have all three elements on one line when there's enough horizontal space in the container (ex: the browser width)
- To have **all** the elements wrap vertically when there's not enough horizontal space to position them all horizontally.

Flexbox does a wonderful job of all of these points, *except* for the last requirement. I can't force *all* of the elements to wrap if there's less than enough space to have all of them on one line.

I'm using a fairly straightforward flexbox setup to achieve the layout:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}

select {
    flex-basis: 10em;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.divider {
    flex-basis: 3em;
    flex-grow: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The problem with this is that, if the container width is set to any amount that's wide enough for one select plus the divider, it will wrap the end select, but *not the divider*. I'll get a select plus a divider on one line, which looks ugly.

This fiddle illustrates the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/5s0yf74w/1/

Is it possible to achieve my desired result by tweaking the CSS while retaining the general flexbox layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that exactly what you want is possible without JS based iterative layout logic (you know, let the browser render, calculate widths and conditionally add/ remove classes).
I think however that the solution given in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovxh1bt2/) is a sane CSS only approach. There are basically two layouts, the *wide* one where I only made one change `flex-wrap: nowrap;` to prevent the nasty case you describe where not all three elements are wrapped. And the *narrow* one which overrides the the flex-direction to `flex-direction: column;`. Both can easily be switched with applying a proper media-query with a sane `min-width`.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are asking, but (may be) even better. 
You can set it without any divider. You will get the illusion of the divider when needed, but no divider when not

```css
#wide {
    width: 31em;
}
#narrow {
    width: 10em;
  top: 100px;
}


.container {
  position: absolute;
   border: solid red 1px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, blue 5px, transparent 5px);
}
.fakecontainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: -1em;
}

select {
    flex-basis: 11em;
    flex-grow: 1;
    
    margin-right: 1em;
}

select:nth-child (2) {
    flex-basis: 10em;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="wide">
<div class="fakecontainer">
    <select multiple>
        <option>One of many</option>
        <option>Two of many</option>
    </select>
    <select multiple>
        <option>One of many</option>
        <option>Two of many</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="narrow">
<div class="fakecontainer">
    <select multiple>
        <option>One of many</option>
        <option>Two of many</option>
    </select>
    <select multiple>
        <option>One of many</option>
        <option>Two of many</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

You just need an extra element, fakecontainer , to do some hack with the margins

If you really want a divider in the narrow option, you just need to do a similar trick with the bottom margin (let me know if this is the case)